# When map over a function is useful when you have andThen

Tags: scala, scalaz

With Scalaz, a function can be mapped over another function. When would I want to use `map` over `andThen`? Is there a clear advantage using `map`? Thanks

For example,

```
val f: Int => Int = (a) => a + 10

val g: Int => Int = (a) => a * 100

(f map g map {_*3})(10) == (f andThen g andThen {_*3})(10)  // true
```

Comment: Well `map` works on any functor, not just functions.

Comment: I was thinking about that too. So I can map over a list of option and list of functor but I couldn't figure how to create a list of functors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setting aside implementation details for a moment, `map` *is* `andThen` for functions (under the functor instance for `A => ?`), and it doesn't really make a lot of sense to talk about preferring one over the other if we're talking about functions specifically and not some higher level of abstraction.

What methods like `map` (and type classes like `Functor` more generally) allow us to do is abstract over specific types or type constructors. Suppose we want to write a `incrementResult` method that works on both `A => Int` or `Kleisli[Option, A, Int]`, for example. These types don't have anything in common in terms of inheritance (short of `AnyRef`, which is useless), but `A => ?` and `Kleisli[Option, A, ?]` are both functors, so we could write this:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def incrementResult[F[_]: Functor](f: F[Int]): F[Int] = f.map(_ + 1)
```

And then use it like this (note that I'm using [kind-projector](https://github.com/non/kind-projector) to simplify the type syntax a bit):

```
scala> val plainOldFuncTriple: Int => Int = _ * 3
plainOldFuncTriple: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> val optionKleisliTriple: Kleisli[Option, Int, Int] = Kleisli(i => Some(i * 3))
optionKleisliTriple: scalaz.Kleisli[Option,Int,Int] = Kleisli(<function1>)

scala> val f = incrementResult[Int => ?](plainOldFuncTriple)
f: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> val k = incrementResult[Kleisli[Option, Int, ?]](optionKleisliTriple)
k: scalaz.Kleisli[Option,Int,Int] = Kleisli(<function1>)

scala> f(10)
res0: Int = 31

scala> k(10)
res1: Option[Int] = Some(31)
```

In this case specifically there are better ways to implement this operation, but it shows the general idea—we couldn't write a single method that works for both ordinary functions and Kleisli arrows using `andThen`, but we can with the extra level of abstraction that `map` gives us.

So to answer your question—you'd use `map` if you want to abstract over all type constructors that have a functor instance, but if you're working specifically with functions, `map` *is* `andThen`, and—as long as we're still setting aside implementation details—it doesn't matter which you choose.

---

Footnote: the `map` that Scalaz's `syntax` package gives you for values of types that have functor instances is implemented as an extension method, so there's a tiny bit of overhead (both at compile time and runtime) involved in using `map` instead of `andThen` on a function. If you're only working with functions and don't need the extra abstraction, then, you might as well go with `andThen`.

Comment: We *can* write a single method that works for both using `andThen`: `def incrementResult[~>[_, _] : Compose, A](f: A ~> Int): A ~> Int = f andThen (_ + 1)`

Comment: @JulienRichard-Foy Sure (that's what I meant by "better ways to implement this operation), but that's kind of a distraction since that `andThen` is not the `andThen` on `Function1`, which is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @JulienRichard-Foy how do I fix this? `value andThen is not a member of type parameter ~>[A,Int]`